# How to use gazebo bumper plugin to get contact state?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pull out some data from the contact point of an object, so I chose to use the Gazebo Ros Bumper plug in. I call the plugin in the sensor section of my xml file. But now i don't know how to see my data displayed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45776/how-to-use-gazebo-bumper-plugin-to-get-contact-state?/) by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins), GazeboRosBumper plugin provides contact feedback via ContactsState message. So you will need to subscribe to the topic that is publishing that message.

rostopic (list, info, type...) is your friend.

More generally, you should search on answers.ros (and also pay attention to tags).
When I select the "bumper" tag (or include it as an "Interesting tag" on the right menu), one of the questions that is listed is ["How do I use force sensor/ bumper sensor in Gazebo"](http://answers.ros.org/question/29158/how-do-i-use-force-sensor-bumper-sensor-in-gazebo/) and ["Reading bumper state from PR2"](http://answers.ros.org/question/9368/reading-bumper-state-from-pr2/)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2